# How can I call a function after an interval has finished?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intervals

I have an `$interval` that calls a certain number of times.

When the interval has finished running, I want it to call a final reset function. How can I do this?

ie.

```
  $scope.clickme = function() {
    var i = 0;

    function lerp() {
      alert(i++);
    }

    function fin(){    //how do I call this function? 
        alert ("all done!")
    }

    $interval(lerp, 500, 5);
  };
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h4cn32e6/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The return value of registering an interval function is a promise. This promise will be notified upon each tick of the interval, and will be resolved after count iterations

So:

```
$interval(lerp, 500, 5).then(fin);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$interval` returns a promise, which will be resolved when it has finished executing all of its iterations.

Just use `promise.then` to execute the final task..

```
  $scope.clickme = function() {
    var i = 0;

    function lerp() {
      alert(i++);
    }

    function fin(){
        alert ("all done!")
    }

    var promise = $interval(lerp, 500, 5);

    promise.then(fin);
  };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0wuwnhxo/